# Change LUKS2 password with TPM2 as key

Tags: arch-linux, luks

I accidentally changed the password of my LUKS2 partition to something I can't recover. But I have the partition decrypt with the TPM2 of my laptop. The problem is, that I cannot use the TPM2 as key for cryptsetup. Can someone point me in the right direction to change the password with the TPM as key?

Comment: does `dmsetup table --showkeys` still give you the master key?

Comment: The result I get after executing is as follows: `luks: 0 1952363919 crypt aes-xts-plain64 :64:logon:cryptsetup:5d300e6d-3941-4c0c-a7a9-3662ef3aa91b-d0 0 259:2 32768 1 allow_discards`

Comment: OK, that's not the master key, it's the keyring... you'd have to open it with `--disable-keyring` option to get the master key this way. With the master key, you could create a new LUKS header from scratch. If that can't be done, you have to elaborate a little how you set up cryptsetup+TPM

Comment: Running the following command: `cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p2 --key-file <(dmsetup table --showkey /dev/mapper/luks | awk '{print$5}' | xxd -r -p) --disable-keyring` I get the following message: `No key available with this passphrase.`. I have setup cryptsetup+TPM following this guide: https://odysee.com/@daimarstein:d/arch-install-guide-tpm-secureboot:e

Comment: OK, it seems to me that systemd does not offer a path for one to add a new passphrase using just the TPM. systemd-cryptenroll can do passwords and recovery keys but it will ask you for a passphrase all the same. -- It's complicated, back up files and do it over.

Comment: It still boots up normally since the TPM key is properly sealed. So I will live with that for now.